# Use a service and binder from a library project

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-library, android-binder

I'm currently working on a radio **streaming** application.
To do the work i decided to create a **Library project** to do some **code refactoring**

So in my Library project i have :

- StreamingService.java
- StreamingPlayerMP.java
- StreamingPlayerAAC.java
- StreamingCallback.java
- StreamingNotification.java
- StreamingState.java
- StreamingStation.java

Do i need to define the service in both the **library manifest** and the **application Manifest** ?

```
   <service
        android:name=".StreamingService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
```

Do i need to put permissions in both the **library manifest** and the **application Manifest** too ?

Currently the Service/players/callback are **ready for use**. I want to manage the service with a **ServiceConnection** and a **binder** to the main activity :

```
public void bindToService() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StreamingService.class);
    if (((TestingApplication) getApplication()).MediaPlayerServiceRunning()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "bindToService--");
        // Bind to LocalService
        bindService(intent, _connectionStreaming, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
    else {
        Log.i(TAG, "bindToService--startService--");
        startService(intent);
        boolean isBound = bindService(intent, _connectionStreaming, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Log.d(TAG, "IS SERVICE BOUND--" + isBound);
    }
}

private ServiceConnection   _connectionStreaming    = new ServiceConnection() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder serviceBinder) {

                                                                Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected--");
                                                                // service
                                                                MediaPlayerBinder binder = (MediaPlayerBinder) serviceBinder;
                                                                TestingApplication._mediaPlayerService = binder.getServiceInstance();
                                                                // callback
                                                                TestingApplication._mediaPlayerService.setInitCallBack(MainActivity.this);
                                                                TestingApplication._mediaPlayerService.initializePlayer(getString(R.string.url_podcast_mp3_test));
                                                                _bound = true;
                                                            }

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {

                                                                Log.d(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected--");
                                                                _bound = false;
                                                            }
                                                        };
```

And the binder methods (located in the service):

```
private final Binder                    _binder         = new MediaPlayerBinder();

public class MediaPlayerBinder extends Binder {
    public StreamingService getServiceInstance() {

        Log.i(TAG, "getServiceInstance--");
        return StreamingService.this;
    }
}

@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onBind--");
        return _binder;
    }
```

The service is a foregroundservice :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand--");
    _runningCallBack.onBufferingStarted();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

If you have a complete solution you are welcome !
Advices are welcome too